# Django and c9.io - connection refused?

Tags: python, django

When I start the server using `python manage.py runserver localhost:8000`, it appears to connect, giving me:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 25, 2016 - 00:30:23
Django version 1.9.4, using settings 'deanslist.settings'
Starting development server at http://localhost:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

And nothing else. However, in my browser window, going to localhost:8000 gives me an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. This has happened on every other port I've tried as well. I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong. Anyone else have any ideas?

For the record, my `manage.py` looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "deanslist.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

And the script I used to set up my virtual environment looks like this:

```
LogFile=./setup_log
ErrFile=./setup_err

# Detect the platform
OS="`uname`"
case $OS in
  'Linux')
    OS='Linux'
    ;;
  'Darwin') 
    OS='Mac'
    ;;
  'AIX') ;;
  *) ;;
esac

function install_mac_dependencies() {

    brew update
    brew upgrade
    brew prune
    brew install python3

    if [ $(xcode-select -p) == 2 ]
    then
        xcode-select --install
    fi

}

# Install system dependencies w/package manager for Ubuntu
function install_dependencies () {
    sudo apt-get install python3-dev
}

# Setup the python virtual environment
function setup_env () {
    pip install virtualenv

    if [[ "$OS" == "Mac" ]]
    then
        virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 venv
        source ./venv/bin/activate
        pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
        env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
    else
        virtualenv -p python3 venv
        source ./venv/bin/activate
        pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
    fi

    pip install -r requirements.txt
}

function local_db_setup() {
    while true; do
        read -p "Run the setup script now? y/n   " answer
        case $answer in
            [yY]* ) echo "[!] Migrating models to local database"
                    python manage.py makemigrations
                    python manage.py migrate
                    break;;

            [nN]* ) echo "Exiting database update module..."; exit;;

            * )     echo "Dude, just enter Y or N, please."; break ;;
        esac
    done
}

# Check script's compatability 
if [[ ! "$OS" == "Linux" ]] && [[ ! "$OS" == "Mac" ]]
then
    echo "[-] Exiting, setup script currently only tested on macOS Sierra and Ubuntu"
    exit;
fi

# Initiate the setup
while true; do 
    read -p "Run the setup script now? y/n   " answer
    case $answer in
       [yY]* )  echo "[*] Initiating setup for platform: $OS";
                # Dependencies
                echo "Installing python3-dev. This may require sudo privileges..."
                if [ ! "$OS" == "Linux" ] 
                then
                    brew help > /dev/null
                    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                    then
                        install_homebrew        
                    else
                        install_mac_dependencies > "$LogFile" 2> "$ErrFile";
                    fi
                else
                    install_dependencies > "$LogFile" 2> "$ErrFile";
                fi

                # Python Environment
                echo "Creating the virtual environment..."
                setup_env >> "$LogFile" 2>> "$ErrFile";

                break;;

       [nN]* ) echo "Exiting setup..."; exit;;

       * )     echo "Dude, just enter Y or N, please."; break ;;
    esac
done


# Check for errors
if [ ! -s "$ErrFile" ]
then
    echo "[+] Setup successful! No errors detected"
    echo "[*] Cleaning and exiting..."
    rm "$ErrFile"
    rm "$LogFile"
    exit
else

    if [[ $(wc -l <$ErrFile) -eq 1 ]]
    then
        if grep -q "already installed" "$ErrFile"; then
            echo "[+] Setup successful! No errors detected"
            echo "[*] Cleaning and exiting..."
            rm "$ErrFile"
            rm "$LogFile"

            # Dev database setup
            local_db_setup;

            exit
        fi
    fi
    echo "[-] Setup failed, check $ErrFile for errors"
fi
```

Comment: @AidanPelisson , just to be sure, are you running the server on your local machine, as opposed to over ssh somewhere?

Comment: I am running on my local machine